Implementing Excel VBA code utilising Arrays into Access VBA code utilising Recordsets
to prefix, I am incredibly new to VBA (around 1 month on/off experience). I managed to write some code to aggregate lines in an array based on certain conditions, which would then be implemented into some code in an access database. Much to my demise, when trying to implement, I quickly learned that Excel VBA and Access VBA do not work the same way, and I am having trouble trying to replace the array reference with a recordset reference. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is a snippet of my placeholder data, which will then be fed from access with the same columns:
Placeholder Dataset
Below is the code in excel VBA I used to filter for unqiue portfolio numbers and aggregating all lines with the same portfolio number. Currently the output has one line with the correct "Min" (the "Max" is set to 100), and a second line with the correct "Max" (the "Min" is set to 0). These need to be combined, to have one line with the correct min and max, deleting any other lines with the same portfolio number:
Sub RemDup()

    Dim raw_array, unq_array, temp, min_wght, max_wght, temp2, site_name, asset_class, neutral, class_weight, min_raw, max_raw As Variant
    Dim c_row, c_row2, r_length, c_length, unq_row, unq_row2 As Long
    
    'Placeholder. The data for raw_array should come from an acces recordset.
    raw_array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    unq_array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G1").Value

    'Main part 1 of code. Filter unique values and place into second array
    For c_row = LBound(raw_array, 1) To UBound(raw_array, 1)
        site_name = raw_array(c_row, 1)
        temp = raw_array(c_row, 2)
        asset_class = raw_array(c_row, 3)
        min_wght = raw_array(c_row, 4)
        max_wght = raw_array(c_row, 5)
        neutral = raw_array(c_row, 6)
        class_weight = raw_array(c_row, 7)
        
        For c_row2 = LBound(unq_array, 1) To UBound(unq_array, 1)
            If Not temp = unq_array(c_row2, 2) Then
                GoTo skipsubloop
            Else
                GoTo skiploop
            End If
skipsubloop:
        Next c_row2
        r_length = UBound(unq_array, 1)
        c_length = UBound(unq_array, 2)
        unq_array = Application.Transpose(unq_array)
        ReDim Preserve unq_array(1 To c_length, 1 To r_length + 1)
        unq_array = Application.Transpose(unq_array)
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 1) = site_name
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 2) = temp
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 3) = asset_class
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 4) = min_wght
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 5) = max_wght
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 6) = neutral
        unq_array(r_length + 1, 7) = class_weight
skiploop:
    Next c_row

    'Main part 2 of code. Use unique values to aggregate rows according to certain condition.
    For unq_row = LBound(unq_array, 1) + 1 To UBound(unq_array, 1)
        temp2 = unq_array(unq_row, 2)
        
        For unq_row2 = LBound(raw_array, 1) + 1 To UBound(raw_array, 1)
            If temp2 = raw_array(unq_row2, 2) Then
                min_raw = raw_array(unq_row2, 4)
                max_raw = raw_array(unq_row2, 5)
                unq_array(unq_row, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Max(min_raw, unq_array(unq_row, 4))
                unq_array(unq_row, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Min(max_raw, unq_array(unq_row, 5))
            End If
        Next unq_row2
    Next unq_row
    
End Sub

the then looks something like this:
Output data
I know effectively nothing about SQL and Access. I'm not looking for someone to translate the whole code for me, I'm just struggling to see where to even start with the process, or if my approach is completely wrong. Even some pointers would be appreciated, or perhaps even knowing if this is out of the scope for a beginner would help.
Thank everyone in advance!

Copy from recordsets to arrays, then proceed with the existing code?

Hey, I tried going about that approach, but was instantly met with the error that the .Transpose method was not available when I tried running the code in Access...

What is the source of the raw data, if you're now working in Access and not getting that data from an Excel worksheet?

You could write a small function to extend the array without needing to perform any transpose actions.

The data comes from a recordset fed by an access database. I simply copied an extract into a worksheet to work on my code more easily, since the query in access takes a minute to run each time. The idea was to implement the code into access, to directly be fed by the recordset.

Could you maybe give me a pointer or two regarding the function you are talking about? I searched for a while and couldn't find a better solution (which I could understand) to dynamically add rows to a 2D array in vba.

Added - since your source data is in Access you can just use SQL for the rollup.  Something like:
select sitename, portfolio, assetclass, Min([Min]) as minVal,
       Max([Max]) as maxVal, Neutral, Weight 
from tablename 
group by  sitename, portfolio, assetclass, Neutral, Weight


Without really addressing the bigger picture of what it means to move from Excel to Access...
Since you're only using Transpose as a workaround so you can resize unq_array, you can instead do that directly using a Function:
Sub tester()
    Dim arr
    arr = Range("A1:D5").Value 'Testing this in excel...
    Debug.Print UBound(arr, 1) '5
    arr = AddRows(arr)
    Debug.Print UBound(arr, 1) '6
End Sub

'Resize first dimension of 2D array `arr` by `numrows`
Function AddRows(arr, Optional numrows As Long = 1)
    Dim newArr, r As Long, c As Long
    ReDim newArr(1 To UBound(arr, 1) + numrows, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            newArr(r, c) = arr(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    AddRows = newArr
End Function

Transpose:
'transpose a 2D array
Function MyTranspose(arr)
    Dim newArr, r As Long, c As Long, lbc As Long, lbr As Long, ubc As Long, ubr As Long
    lbr = LBound(arr, 1): ubr = UBound(arr, 1)
    lbc = LBound(arr, 2): ubc = UBound(arr, 2)
    ReDim newArr(lbc To ubc, lbr To ubr)
    For r = lbr To ubr
        For c = lbc To ubc
            newArr(c, r) = arr(r, c) 'transpose
        Next c
    Next r
    MyTranspose = newArr
End Function


I really appreciated the time you put into this. I've been doing some testing, and the function works really well, removing the need for transposing. I would've never come up with that solution myself... One big issue I am still facing, is that when I try to transfer the data from the recordset to the array (using raw_array = rs.GetRows(rs.recordcount)), the dimensions are switched around. Do you know a way I could get around that issue?

You can write a similar function to AddRows, which instead of making a resized copy of arr makes a transposed copy - you don't need to make many changes....  Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

See above for transpose function

Incredible. Thank you so much for your patience, you're a wizard Tim.
